# Scheduling a 10 team tournament, 5 locations, 5 time slots

Tags: combinatorics

There is a competition going on where 5 different games are occurring at 5 different stations. Also, there are only 5 time slots during the competition. Once the time runs out, every team rotates to another station. There are 10 teams and each of the teams has to play at a different station. The team can not stay at the station and must relocate and they can not return back to the station. Once a team arrives at a different station, they have to compete against a different team (so a team can not play the same team twice). Finally, there can only be 2 teams at a station.

**To Clarify, here are the rules:**

- there are only 5 time slots (this determines when the teams change stations)
- team must move after time runs out
- team must play a different team when they arrive at a new station
- there can only be 2 teams at a station at once (the two teams that are competing against eachother)

**How does one schedule this with these restrictions?** Please help.

Here is what I have done:

Guess and check, I've tried just filling out a 5x5 grid (5 stations vs 5 time slots) and I would always get stuck on the last line. The last line could not be filled out as there were repeat of teams at a station, or two teams that have already competed would compete again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the ten teams into two groups of five. Scheduling with the given restrictions is equivalent to finding a Graeco-Latin square of order 5; the two Latin squares correspond to the two groups of teams.

The following is an admissible schedule, numbering the teams from 0 to 9. Each column is one venue and each timeslot is one row.

```
01 27 43 69 85
23 49 65 81 07
45 61 87 03 29
67 83 09 25 41
89 05 21 47 63
```

Comment: how did you calculate this? is there an algorithm?

Comment: @RickyKim I just plucked the Latin square from Wikipedia. There are such arrangements for any $2n$ teams, except 12 teams.

Answer (score 1):

Since 10 is twice an odd number, the following is easy to remember:

Arrange the events in a circle.  Half the teams move clockwise from one event to the next; the other half move anticlockwise.

Comment: Thanks! this helped me visualize the problem and understand better.